# Get weekly score from table width date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
    -------------------------------------------
    |id      |duration  |date           |uid  |
    -------------------------------------------
    |1       |20        |1392479414     |1    |
    |2       |60        |1392561057     |1    |
    |3       |50        |1392598128     |2    |
    |...                                      |
    |...                                      |
    -------------------------------------------
```

Is there an easy way to get a weekly cumulative score from this, without manually calculating the week start/end dates, and querying each one to get the score between those dates?

So that I get:

```
    ---------------
    |sum_duration |
    ---------------
    |2450         |
    |12350        |
    |400          |
    |...          |
    |...          |
    ---------------
```

Many thanks.

Comment: exactly how does that date value correspond to an actual human-readable date? It's definitely not a mysql date, so you wouldn't be able to do a simple `GROUP BY year(date), month(date)` and use a rollup query.

Comment: It's a UNIX timestamp...

Comment: then `from_unixtimestamp(date)` and whatever grouping logic you need applied on top of that.

Comment: @user3882556 . . . Please edit your question and show an example of the output that you want.

Comment: @user3882556, I like your question. It helps me have more knowledge. Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use MySQL, you can use `WEEK` or `YEARWEEK` function. I think YEARWEEK is better. Here's MySQL document http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

`SELECT SUM(duration) FROM table_name GROUP BY YEARWEEK(date)`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. `GROUP BY` the week number.

#### Get all results

```
SELECT SUM(`duration`) AS sum_duration, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%U') as week_no
FROM `foo`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%U')
```

With your data set, we'd get;

```
+--------------+---------+
| sum_duration | week_no |
+--------------+---------+
|           20 | 06      |
|          110 | 07      |
+--------------+---------+
2 rows in set
```

#### Get certain week

If you want to get a specific week, just append `HAVING week_no = '07'` to the end. (Replace `07` with your week number. For example;

```
SELECT
    SUM(`duration`) AS sum_duration,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%U') AS week_no
FROM
    `foo`
GROUP BY
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%U')
HAVING
    week_no = '07';
```

We would get the following result;

```
+--------------+---------+
| sum_duration | week_no |
+--------------+---------+
|          110 | 07      |
+--------------+---------+
1 row in set
```

Comment: SELECT SUM(duration) AS week_duration FROM cdu_user_progress WHERE uid = 156 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('date'), '%U') seems to only return one record...

Comment: `uid` isn't in your table from your original post, neither is `duration`

Comment: Simply add `%Y` to the `DATE_FORMAT`. For example; `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('date'), '%U %Y')`. You can get the date formats here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp